# Android swapping tabs

Tags: android, tabs

I'm trying to implement 3 swapping tabs. I'm following some tutorials from YouTube. But my code's not running properly. I found many solutions, tried those solutions, did exactly same code but while running my project, it crushes. my codes below:

main java class

```
package io.github.hackimti.curiousity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {

    ActionBar actionBar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.main_pager1);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab A").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab B").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab C").setTabListener(this));
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public MyAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if(position == 0){
            fragment = new FA();
        }
        if(position == 1){
            fragment = new FB();
        }
        if(position == 2){
            fragment = new FC();
        }
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

main xml file

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_pager1">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: What issues are you facing?

Comment: Apps not running. When trying to run it shows "unfortunately, curiosity has stopped"  curiosity is the apps name

Comment: Ok. Post the error log.

Comment: log's are creating fast,,, can't find exact error log

Comment: crash line will be shown in blue color check that

Comment: 03-12 19:00:49.427 18250-18250/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at io.github.touhidul_mti.curiousity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)

Comment: "MainActivity.java:43" is in blue color

Comment: previous line      03-12 19:00:49.427 18250-18250/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Moving mouse cursor on some of the code shows "deprecated"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you trying to achieve this is an old way.

For sliding pages with tabs do following.

Download or copy following two files on github and paste your project. this is same as on developers.google.com except setDistributeEvenly method.

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java

activity_main.xml

```
<your.package.name.SlidingTabLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
 </your.package.name.SlidingTabLayout>

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

MyAdapter.java (Here i used two pages only)

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
{ 
    String[] title = {"All","Favourites"};
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) { 
        super(fm); 
    } 
    @Override 
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment=null; 
         if (position==0)
            fragment= new All(); 
             if (position==1)
                fragment= new Favourites(); 
        return fragment; 
    } 
    @Override 
     public int getCount() { 
        return 2; 
    } 
       @Override 
       public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
             return title[position];
    } 
 }
```

tab_view.xml (view of tab only , if you want u can also use ImageView here)

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        />
   </FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 private SlidingTabLayout tabLayout;
 private ViewPager pager;
 tabLayout= (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs); 
 pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager); 
 tabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.tab_view,R.id.tab_title); 
 MyPagerAdapter adapter =  new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); 
 pager.setAdapter(adapter); 
 tabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true); 
 tabLayout.setViewPager(pager);
```

Above code is fine. but latest way to achive swiping tabs with pages is throug android support design library.